# react native FlatList scrollToItem error

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I'm using React Native `FlatList` component. when clicking on an list item , it adds more items to the list and scrolls to one of them using the function `ScrollToItem`.
Sometimes when scrolling i get this error on android:

> scrollToIndex should be used in conjunction with getItemLayout or onScrollToIndexFailed, otherwise there is no way to know the location of offscreen indices or handle failures.

I tried to implement the `getItemLayout` function, but my items doesn't have fixed height, and also i have multiple types of items with different heights.

- Maybe there is a way to handle these cases inside
  `onScrollToIndexFailed`?
- What are best practices for this kind of need?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the ScrollToItem function requires each item to have the same height. You can use the function scrollTo.

example:

```
renderItem={({item})=>{<View onLayout={(e)=> console.log(e.nativeEvent.layout.y)}/>}} /*save each item location*/
```

Then call function scrollTo({x: 0, y: /* which you have saved before */, animated: true})

Hope it works for you